# Elasticsearch nested type disappears

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I created mapping with field `parameter` as a nested field when I am inserting data, I can see that mapping contains this field as nested but after some time this field is no longer nested and a bunch of my queries doesn't work.

Do you have any idea why `nested` type disappears?

I am using
Spring version -> 2.4.1
Elasticsearch -> 7.8.0

My mapping is created by spring data:

```
@Document(indexName = "data")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Product(
        @Id
        val id: String? = null,
        val category: String,
        val name: String,
        val imagesUrls: List<String>,
        @Field(type = FieldType.Double)
        val price: Double?,
        @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
        val parameters: List<Parameter>?
)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "disappears"? where does it disappear from?

Comment: So, basically, it disappears from mapping. When I am inserting data and I am checking the mapping I can see `"type":"nested"`, but after some time, mapping doesn't contain this `"type":"nested`.

Comment: how do you insert data? Only with the Spring application? Is there some other process deleting and newly creating the index like some time based rolling index stuff? Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories write the mapping when the index is created initialliy by repository and never changed afterwards.

Comment: I insert data only with Spring and I don't have any other processes which modifying or deleting data. I added default value to parameters, so far everything looks good.

Comment: That's strange. But Spring Data does only automatically write a mapping when creating a new index and not on existing indices. And even if it would, it would consider the nested definition. This behaviour is not reproducible for me at the moment.